# How do I get Emacs ido-dired to list directories first at the top, above files?

Tags: emacs, dired, ido-mode

In GNU Emacs, using ido-mode, ido-dired mixes files and directories in the list.

How do I get Emacs ido-dired to list directories at the top, above files?

(Bonus question: How do I get ido-dired to list files in case-insensitive order?)